# How to check if event is submitted?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).on('keyup submit click', '#myForm', function(e) {
    console.log(e.type);
});
```

Here `e.type` returns either click or keyup but not the status of submission. How can I check if the form was submitted?

Comment: You can refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7410096/5971348) for help

Comment: You need to attach the `submit` event handler to the form directly, not to the submit button.

Comment: The status itself is probably not resolved by the time the code is evaluated, have you tried adding a Promise to it?https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `document` you attached the handler to, doesn't have a `submit` event, hence it won't fire.

What you could do though, if not to attach the `submit` handler to the `form`, would be to check if the `e.target` is the actual submit button, e.g. check if it has the `type="submit"` attribute.

```
if (e.target.hasAttribute('type') &&
    e.target.getAttribute('type').toLowerCase() == 'submit') {...}
```

With that you could check if the submit button were clicked.

If the submission is called in any other way, you need to watch that.

*Do note, if you have a validation function called, the `form` might not actually be submitted, so if you need to know it were, you need to attach the `submit` handler to the `form`.*

Comment: Thank you, that helped me a lot!